# SimpleDateFormat Unparseable date only on phone

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to parse a string from my database which has "Mon Jul 18 12:58:05 2022" string as value. Weirdly it only works with emulator. But, if i try to uses my app in my phone it throws Unparseable date error. My phone is using android 9 which use sdk 28, so i think it should be fine. I alread tried to remove the timezone which in many cases could cause the problem. But, after i remove it and the error still happen. It took me sometime to figure this out, but in the end i still got no answer. I just wanted to know what causing such problem and how to fix it?

Here is my code :

```
 ref.child(currentData.id.toString()).child("onwork_start").get().addOnSuccessListener {
                val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy")
                val time = sdf.parse(it.value.toString())
                val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm")
                val show_time = date.format(time)
                holder.tv_konfirmasi_bill.text = show_time.toString()
```

Comment: What's the default Locale on your device? Patterns like `EEE` and `MMM` are Locale-sensitive.

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: Include your date value here

Comment: "Mon Jul 18 12:58:05 2022" my date value from my database should be like this

Comment: Set locale to the formatters

Comment: @GobuCSG Thanks, adding the locale formatters work. I just add Locale.ENGLISH to all my formatters